# Grab CSS Classes from HTML

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2

So I was wondering if anyone knows of a package/plugin for sublime or a service that lists class attributes within an HTML snippet.

For example I like to markup then work on the css. I keep finding myself splitting sublime into two halves and just manually scrolling through the HTML on the left and rewriting the the actual class name styles on the right.

Basically I have:

```
<section class="home-testimonials">
    <h2 class="home-title">
        <span>Testimonials</span>
    </h2>
    <div class="testimonial-wrapper">
        <!-- Other divs with classes -->
    </div>
</section>
```

And I want a list like this:

- .home-testimonials
- .home-title
- .testimonial-wrapper

If it denotes hierarchy position even better. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Sublime, but with regular JS you can select all elements with `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`, and then extract classes for each element with `element.className`.

Comment: Ah I didn't think of that, however I was looking for something effortless. Nonetheless, if no one posts anything I'll have to do this, thanks for the response.